# How to schedule a cron job in spring boot without using @Scheduled() annotation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cron, job-scheduling, spring-scheduled

In spring boot, can I schedule a spring job by not using `@Scheduled` annotation to a method?

I am working with spring job in the spring boot. I want to schedule a job by using cron expression, but without using `@Scheduled(cron = " ")` annotation to the method.

I know that I can schedule a job inside this method as below.

```
@Scheduled (cron = "0 10 10 10 * ?")

public void execute() { 

   / * some job code * /

}
```

But I want it to be dynamic so that I can take a cron expression as input from the user and schedule it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring boot add new schedule job dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46974272/spring-boot-add-new-schedule-job-dynamically)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I came up with a working example since I found your question interesting and have been interested in this problem before. It's based entirely on the source code so I have no idea if it comes close to following best practice. Nonetheless, you may be able to tune it to your needs. FYI, you don't necessarily need to create a new ScheduledTaskRegistrar object - I figured that since your objective is a dynamic scheduler, you wouldn't be interested in defining your tasks purely in the overwritten method.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TaskScheduler implements SchedulingConfigurer, CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args){SpringApplication.run(TaskScheduler.class, args);}

    List<CronTask> cronTasks;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        CronTask task = this.createCronTask(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now());
            }
        }, "1/10 * * * * *");

        ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar = new ScheduledTaskRegistrar();
        taskRegistrar.addCronTask(task);
        configureTasks(taskRegistrar);
        Thread.sleep(51);

        taskRegistrar.destroy();
        taskRegistrar = null;

        ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar2 = new ScheduledTaskRegistrar();
        taskRegistrar2.addCronTask(task);
        configureTasks(taskRegistrar2);

    }

    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
        // "Calls scheduleTasks() at bean construction time" - docs
        taskRegistrar.afterPropertiesSet();
    }

    public CronTask createCronTask(Runnable action, String expression) {
        return new CronTask(action, new CronTrigger(expression));
    }

}
```

I have experience using cron jobs in Azure and other places. Programming in Java, I have typically used `@Scheduled` with fixed times just for the sake of simplicity. Hope this is useful to you though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working example for these who wants to use `TaskScheduler` without using the `@Scheduled` annotation.

`@Configuration` class

```
@Configuration
public class SchedulerConfig implements SchedulingConfigurer {

    final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(SchedulerConfig.class);

    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar scheduledTaskRegistrar) {
        LOGGER.debug("Creating Async Task Scheduler");
        scheduledTaskRegistrar.setTaskScheduler(taskScheduler());
    }

    // This is mandatory otherwise it will to be able to find bean of       
    // taskScheduler. Without this it was giving runtime error says, can not find 
    // taskScheduler bean.
    @Bean
    public TaskScheduler taskScheduler() {
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler scheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        scheduler.setPoolSize(20); // Better to read it from property file.
        scheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("ThreadScheduler-");
        scheduler.initialize();
        return scheduler;
    }
}
```

Scheduler Class which is called from Application class.

```
@Component
public class MyTaskScheduler {

    private TaskScheduler taskScheduler;
    // Here we are auto-wiring taskScheduler, that's why need to create 
   // taskScheduler bean in configuration class
    @Autowired
    public void setScheduler(TaskScheduler scheduler) {
        this.taskScheduler = scheduler;
    }

    public void schedule() {
        taskScheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("I am running after every 1 second");
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

If in any chance `@Configuration` annotation is not working so put `@EnableConfigurationProperties` at main running class.
Make sure that you put `@EnableScheduling` at `Application` class, so main runnable class will look like

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class MainApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
    
    @Autowired
    MyTaskScheduler myTaskScheduler;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(MainApplication.class);
        SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class, args);
        logger.info("Application started");
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        myTaskScheduler.schedule();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is similar to the two previous ones, but is more compact because it leverages the scheduling registrar already provided in the application context:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class Schedule implements SchedulingConfigurer {

    private final transient WorkflowTriggerService workflowTriggerService;

    public Schedule(final WorkflowTriggerService workflowTriggerService) {
        this.workflowTriggerService = workflowTriggerService;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureTasks(final ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
        for (final WorkflowTrigger trigger : workflowTriggerService.getWorkflowTriggersWithSchedules()) {
            taskRegistrar.addCronTask(new WorkflowTask(trigger), trigger.getSchedule());
        }
    }

}
```

Each WorkflowTrigger returned by the service has its own cron schedule, and therefore allows dynamic registration of scheduled tasks that are not known at compilation time.