# Cron job in Google app engine with spring boot

Tags: java, google-app-engine, spring-boot, cron-task

There are answers on how to [schedule tasks on Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35064563/what-is-best-way-to-schedule-task-in-spring-boot-application)

There are also links on how to create a [Cron Job in App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml)

I am using Spring Boot for Google App Engine, so how can I have Cron jobs using Spring Boot?

Answer (score 2):

The cron service in GAE is simply a scheduler for `GET` requests to certain URLs handled by the application. From the very cron documentation reference you posted:

> A cron job will invoke a URL, using an HTTP GET request, at a given
>   time of day.

So all you have to do is:

- Configure [the schedule](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml#defining_the_cron_job_schedule) of the jobs and the URLs to be invoked
- Add handlers for those URLs into your app code to perform the necessary actions for the jobs

You can also validate that the `GET` requests for those URLs [are only coming from App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml#validating_cron_requests).