# How can I start @Scheduled method with concrete scheduler?

Tags: java, spring, scheduler

I have scheduler:

```
@Bean("one")
ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler(){
    ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    threadPoolTaskScheduler.setPoolSize(5);
    threadPoolTaskScheduler.setAwaitTerminationSeconds(60);
    threadPoolTaskScheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("Test-");
    return threadPoolTaskScheduler;
}

@Bean("two")
ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler2(){
    ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    threadPoolTaskScheduler.setPoolSize(50);
    threadPoolTaskScheduler.setAwaitTerminationSeconds(60);
    threadPoolTaskScheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("Test2-");
    return threadPoolTaskScheduler;
}
```

And method:

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000L)
public void test() {
```

And Second method:

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000L)
public void test2() {
```

How can I configure each `@Scheduled` method with concrete scheduler?

If I implement it like this:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class MyScheduler {

    private final ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskSchedulerFirst;
    private final ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskSchedulerSecond;
    private final TestBean testBean;

    public MyScheduler(@Qualifier("first") ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskSchedulerFirst, @Qualifier("second")ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskSchedulerSecond, TestBean testBean) {
        this.taskSchedulerFirst = taskSchedulerFirst;
        this.taskSchedulerSecond = taskSchedulerSecond;
        this.testBean = testBean;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void test() {
        taskSchedulerFirst.scheduleAtFixedRate(testBean::test, 1000L);
        taskSchedulerSecond.scheduleAtFixedRate(testBean::test2, 1000L);
    }
```

Bouth schedulers not used and used TaskExecutor:

```
2018-09-05 11:10:30.812  INFO 10724 --- [TaskExecutor-41] com.example.scheduling.TestBean          : hz
2018-09-05 11:10:31.747  INFO 10724 --- [TaskExecutor-43] com.example.scheduling.TestBean          : hz
2018-09-05 11:10:31.748  INFO 10724 --- [TaskExecutor-46] com.example.scheduling.TestBean          : hz2
2018-09-05 11:10:32.747  INFO 10724 --- [TaskExecutor-45] com.example.scheduling.TestBean          : hz
2018-09-05 11:10:32.748  INFO 10724 --- [TaskExecutor-48] com.example.scheduling.TestBean          : hz2
2018-09-05 11:10:33.747  INFO 10724 --- [TaskExecutor-47]
```

But used `TaskExecutor` why?

Comment: Did you remove the `@Scheduled` annotation from the bean methods after your edit?

Comment: bean methods after not @Scheduled befour and after edit. Only Async

Comment: You should not need the `@Async` annotation. This will make spring use a different thread pool for execution. Simply remove this annotation an you should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR** No

According to [Spring scheduling](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-task-scheduler) they are different implementations of TaskScheduler abstraction

1. ThreadPoolTaskScheduler as implementation:

   > ThreadPoolTaskScheduler, can be used whenever external thread management is not a requirement. Internally, it delegates to a ScheduledExecutorService instance. ThreadPoolTaskScheduler actually implements Spring's TaskExecutor interface as well, so that a single instance can be used for asynchronous execution as soon as possible as well as scheduled, and potentially recurring, executions.
2. @Scheduled as annotation support for task scheduling

> The @Scheduled annotation can be added to a method along with trigger metadata.

See also [answer for best way to schedule task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35064563/what-is-best-way-to-schedule-task-in-spring-boot-application) , most voted:

> The simplest way to schedule tasks in Spring is to create method annotated by @Scheduled in spring managed bean.

Comment: I did not understand anything from the answer. somehow all smeared. Can I set concrete tasckScheduler to method with @Scheduled annotation or not?

Comment: @ip696 TL;DR No, they are different implementation of scheduling

Comment: but if I configure 1 tasckScheduler and one @Scheduled method - this method use this tasckScheduler.

Answer (score 1):

When using the `@Scheduled` annotation there is no out-of-the-box support to use different thread pools for different beans. You can configure the thread pool to be used by implementing `SchedulingConfigurer` in your `@Configuration` class.

I think the implementation after your edit should work. You probably only need to call `threadPoolTaskScheduler.initialize()` directly after creating the scheduler like this:

```
@Bean("two")
ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler2(){
    ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    threadPoolTaskScheduler.initialize(); // initialize scheduler
    threadPoolTaskScheduler.setPoolSize(50);
    threadPoolTaskScheduler.setAwaitTerminationSeconds(60);
    threadPoolTaskScheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("Test2-");
    return threadPoolTaskScheduler;
}
```

This will create the scheduler's internal executor, that is used the actually execute stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the [`SchedulingConfigurer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/SchedulingConfigurer.html) in config class and override it's `configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar scheduledTaskRegistrar)` method. In the overridden method register your `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler`:

```
    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar scheduledTaskRegistrar) {
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    ...

        scheduledTaskRegistrar.setTaskScheduler(threadPoolTaskScheduler);
    }
```